# What's efficient way to convert UTC time to local in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, utc, localtime

I have a table with a column that saves a date in UTC. When selecting it I need to convert to local time based on the user's saved TimezoneOffset, which is an integer. Currently, I have a function to convert from UTC to local time like this:

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertUTCTimeToLocal]
(   
@UserTimezoneOffset int,
@DateToConvert Datetime
)
RETURNS  Datetime
AS
BEGIN
-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @LocalTime Datetime

 --Convert start time and end time to UTC time    
SET @LocalTime = DATEADD(hh,  @UserTimezoneOffset, @DateToConvert)

RETURN @LocalTime
END
```

And use it as

```
Select dbo.ConvertUTCTimeToLocal(@UserTimezoneOffset, myTable.CollectedDate) 
From myTable
```

The problem is my table is large and it causes a big performance issue. Is there a better way to handle this?

Thank you!